# IF THEN loop not setting Value correctly

Tags: vba, excel

I have an If...Then loop nested inside of a For loop that is supposed to assign values from an SQL recordset to VBA values so they can be assigned to excel cells.  I have verified that the recordset has values, and that what I am trying to do can be done without the For and If..Then loops.  However, the values seem to be empty whenever the loop runs through.

Here is my block of code:

```
Dim counter as Integer
Dim fieldName1, fieldName2, etc. As String
Dim fieldName() As Variant

fieldName = Array("fieldName1", "fieldName2", "etc.")
counter = 0

For I = 0 To UBound(fieldName())
        If Not IsNull(recordSet.Fields(counter)) Then
            fieldName(I) = recordSet.Fields(counter).Value
            counter = counter + 1
        Else : fieldName(I) = ""
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
Next I
```

After this executes, which it does successfully without any errors, and I try to assign a value to a cell, it is a blank string.

This will result in an empty string:

```
Range("C8").Select
    With Range("C8")
        Range("C8").Value = fieldName1
    End With
```

Yet this will successfully enter a value into a cell:

```
Range("C8").Select
    With Range("C8")
        Range("C8").Value = recordSet.Fields(4).Value
    End With
```

Comment: `fieldName1` when inside double quotes behaves like a string. Here it is behaving like a variable which was never declared or assigned. Best to use `Option Explicit` at the top of the code. . Change`Range("C8").Value = fieldName1` to `Range("C8").Value = fieldName(1)` I guess you want to pull value from the array?

Comment: Oh, I left something important out then. Thank you for bringing attention to it.  I have declared fieldName1, fieldName2 etc. as String. The array is to iterate through those value names so each will get set to a value pulled from the recordset. So no, I am not pulling data out of the array, I am using the array to set values. Give me one second to update my code to reflect this.

Comment: Okay where do you assign a value to `fieldName1`?

Comment: I wanted to assign a value from the line:
    fieldName(I) = recordSet.Fields(counter).Value

Comment: `I have declared fieldName1, fieldName2 etc. as String. The array is to iterate through those value names so each will get set to a value pulled from the recordset.` You cant declare variables in a loop :)

Comment: That is not the way it works.  See @SiddharthRout first comment for the answer.

Comment: Ah, thank you guys.  My fault for not understanding.  I have done it in Python so I assumed that it was applicable here.

Comment: FWIW `fieldName1` is declared as an implicit `Variant`, not a `String`. It's also never assigned, hence being empty. Also there's no need to `.Select` anything, and the smallest possible scope in VBA is procedure level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Siddharth:

> I have declared fieldName1, fieldName2 etc. as String. The array is to iterate through those value names so each will get set to a value pulled from the recordset.

You cant declare variables in a loop :)